# Програма проверки на дубликат

Tags: python, python-3.x, регулярные-выражения, re

В качестве входных данных у вас есть список строк.
Напишите метод **double_string()** для подсчета количества строк из списка, представленного в виде конкатенации двух строк из этого списка аргументов.

Несколько примеров:

| Тест | Результат |
| --- | --- |
| data = ['aa', 'aaaa', 'abc', 'abcabc', 'qwer', 'qwerqwer'] print(double_string(data)) | 3 |
| data = ['aa', 'abc', 'qwerqwer'] print(double_string(data)) | 0 |

Моя программа не работает должным образом, также я хочу посмотреть, как я могу ее решить, используя регулярные выражения(`import re`).

```py
def double_string(data):
    count = 0
    for i in range(len(data)):
        for j in range(i, len(data)):
            if data[i] + data[j] in data:
                count += 1
    return count
```

[Также мой код не проходит такие тесты:](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sjiCE.png)

Comment: На мой взгляд тесты друг другу противореча. Третий тест видимо предполагает, что повторы строк нужно отбрасывать, а четвёртый наоборот так можно посчитать только если не отбрасывать повторы. Непонятно. Но вы лучше все тесты добавьте в вопрос. Те, которые вы привели, работают ведь у вас правильно.

Comment: Ну то есть для третьего теста достаточно сделать `data = list(set(data))` в начале функции. Но тогда 4-й тест не пройдёт, мне кажется.

Comment: Это все тесты, больше добавить не смогу. Сейчас попробую **data = list(set(data))**

Comment: Я добавил **data = list(set(data))**, результат в 3-ем тесте всё равно не **3** а **2** и в 4-ом тесте не **4** а **2**

Comment: Добавьте лучше данные для всех тестов в вопрос, может кто сообразит тогда, в чём там прикол.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Два теста. Один ваша программа обработает верно, второй провалит:

> ```
> ['a', 'b', 'ab'] -> 1 # всё верно
> ['b', 'a', 'ab'] -> 0 # должно быть 1
> ```

В последнем примере ваша программа не посчитает что `ab` можно составить конкатенацией `b` и `a`, пусть и в обратном порядке.

Ещё один неработающий пример:

> ```
> ['a', 'b', 'ab', 'ab'] -> 1 # должно быть 2
> ```

В этом примере две последние строки можно представить конкатенацией, а вы считаете только одну.

Поправить можно так: строим множество всех возможных конкатенаций, каждый элемент списка проверяем на принадлежность этому множеству:

```
def double_string(data):
    # множество всех возможных конкатенаций
    s = set()
    for v1 in data:
        for v2 in data:
            s.add(v1 + v2)

    # сколько элементов списка найдутся в множестве конкатенаций?
    c = 0
    for v in data:
        if v in s:
            c += 1
    return c
```

Если вы понимаете работу кода выше, то вот вам тоже самое только на настоящем Питоне.

[itertools.product(..., repeat=2)](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.product) строит все пары.

`map(''.join, ...)` конкатенирует элементы пар - делает строки.

`sum(1 for ...)` - способ сосчитать элементы. В Питоне нет функции которая считает длину генератора, это общепринятый заменитель.

```
def double_string(data):
    s = set(map(''.join, itertools.product(data, repeat=2)))
    return sum(1 for v in data if v in s)
```